# Groovy -- What is the difference between this and owner

Tags: groovy, this, owner

according to [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) `this` and `owner` seem to have the same meaning. Reading further I find that `owner` can refer to the enclosing class **or** closure. Is this the only difference? If so, why reserve an entire word just for that?

Comment: Here's a nice article on the topic: http://java.dzone.com/articles/groovy-closures-owner-delegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the enclosing class instance. `owner` refers to the directly enclosing object, which may or may not be the enclosing class instance. For example:

```
def x = { def y = { println this; println owner }; y() }
x()
```

Here `this` refers to the instance of the script class, and `owner` refers to `x`.

Comment: Yep. It's also worthwhile mentioning that `delegate` is slightly different from `owner`. It can be programmatically changed.